# How can I get the index of a key?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm setting up a script and I need to get the index of a specified key in my dict.

```py
dict = {'one' : [1,2], 'two' : [3,4,5], 'three' : [6]}
```

How can I return:

```py
1
```

for the value 4 for example (because the index of 'two' is 1).

**Update**

`list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', ..]`

`dict = {'one' : [1,2], 'two' : [3,4,5], 'three' : [6]}`

By doing this:

```py
for key, value in dict.items():
        if int in value:
            out = key
```

I get the string 'key', but does a way exists to get the 'key' index in another list?

For example: `'two'` will return `1` (its index in list)

**Update 25/06**

`list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', ..]`

`dict = {'one' : [1,3], 'two' : [3,4,5], 'three' : [6]}`

How can I return `one` and `two` if my value is `3`?

Comment: Dictionary keys don't have indexes because dictionaries are unordered. from your example, I think you want the key, whose value contains the number provided. Even then it doesn't make sense to return `1`, instead `one` makes sense (since that is the key in the dictionary)

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe more detailed.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at my answer, you can replace `list(dict.keys()).index(k)` with `my_list.index(k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    dict = {'one' : [1,2], 'two' : [3,4,5], 'three' : [6]}
    test_string = 4
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if test_string in v:
            print(list(dict.keys()).index(k))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is more of an hack rather than intended use of dictionaries.

Comment: I hope you don't name the list as "list", assuming it's called my_list, replace the`print(list(dict.keys()).index(k))` with `print(my_list.index(k))`